# Reset value on route navigate Angular +2

Tags: angular

I have `news.component.ts` that include `ListNews()` function, every routing to my homepage I'm calling `ListNews()` and I send in my header incremental number for paging the news (page "0" , page "5" , page "10" ... etc).

The problem is when I navigate on my site and then return to my homepage, the function called with the last page number ( page "10" ) in my example.

So how can I reset the value if and only if I'm coming from any component using `route.navigate`

Suppose I'm in my profile page component, I use:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);
```

Now in my homepage I want the `page` variable reset to `0` not to previous number

Comment: pass query params and update it.

Answer (score 2):

Add ActivatedRoute to your component, and perform a check. If you're on a root url, reset your paging, otherwise just reuse the old one.

I have no exact code samples, because you don't have any either. But e.g. this could be an example implementation:

```
export class NewsComponent {
    lastPage: number = 0;
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }
    ListNews() {
        if (this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url === 'home') { // or whatever your "home" route is
            this.lastPage = 0;
        }
        // the rest of your code
     }
}
    }
```